# How to change Jenkins default folder on Windows?

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, jenkins, hudson

How to change Jenkins default folder on Windows where Jenkins runs as Windows service. 
I want to change `C:\Users\Coola\.jenkins` folder to `d:\Jenkins` due to lack of space on `C:` partition (Every build takes ~10MB of free space). I don't want to reinstall `Jenkins` as Windows service. I just want to change folder of existing `Jenkins` instance. In case of lack of global solution I could focus only on relocating `jobs` folder.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- Stop Jenkins service
- Move `C:\Users\Coola\.jenkins` folder to `d:\Jenkins`
- Using regedit, change `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Jenkins\ImagePath` to `"d:\Jenkins\jenkins.exe"`
- Start service

Comment: The answer helped. In addition, I had to wipe out the workspaces of all my jobs which use the tfs plugin to get the source code. This was failing with 'Unable to determine the workspace' error.

Comment: I also had to add a new Inbound Rule to Windows Firewall, just duplicating the existing one for c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java.exe for the java.exe in the new folder

Comment: The lower ranked answers that involve editting jenkins.xml allow a cleaner split between code and data.

Comment: My version of Jenkins (installed from .msi) did not create a user based ".jenkins" folder. So, I had to go with a different answer - the convoluted one where a bunch of files had to be moved and the jenkins.xml had to be altered

Answer (score 14):

Apparently, grams' answer works but is not preferred. In Windows software and data/configuration files are supposed to reside in different places. This should be well known to Unix guys, it is basically like having a home directory. However, the wording with regard to JENKINS_HOME is broken anyways as setting an environment variable does not help despite what is being said in the help text.

I used the procedure that is described here: http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2014/02/25/jenkins-home-win/

Basically:

1. Stop Jenkins service
2. Edit entry `<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>` in `jenkins.xml` in the Jenkins installation directory. This will be something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins`. In your case `value` has to be set to `d:\Jenkins`
3. Move Files from the installation directory to the new destination, `d:\Jenkins`, all except (some of them may not exist in a fresh installation)

   - jre folder
   - jenkins.err.log
   - jenkins.exe
   - jenkins.exe.config
   - jenkins.out.log
   - jenkins.war
   - jenkins.war.bak
   - jenkins.war.tmp
   - jenkins.wrapper.log
   - jenkins.xml

     4. Restart the service again.

Comment: This worked for me. I also realized that I didn't need to move the "war" folder as it got regenerated in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins.

Answer (score 5):

When you read [Administering Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) you can read all options how to modify the JENKINS_HOME environment variable.

On [this website](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tomcat) you can read how to configure you Tomcat container to override the JENKINS_HOME environment variable, they advise to create the file $CATALINA_BASE/conf/localhost/jenkins.xml, with the following content:

```
<Context docBase="../jenkins.war">
    <Environment name="JENKINS_HOME" type="java.lang.String" value="/data/jenkins" override="true"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer that worked for me: [Jenkins: How to change JENKINS_HOME on Windows](http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2014/02/25/jenkins-home-win/)

Comment: ty @Carlos! that helped me too. The tip to go to the page; http://localhost:8080/systemInfo which shows all the variables was also extremely  helpful.

Answer (score 2):

And in addition to grams answer, the most important part is creating an environment variable named JENKINS_HOME with value "D:\Jenkins". Without that, on starting Jenkins it would again create the .jenkins folder in your user home folder.

Comment: It may not be necessary. AFAIK it seems that the native windows installer does not create (or need) JENKINS_HOME environment variable.

Check out [issue #JENKINS-13530](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13530)

But I guess it's safer to check JENKINS_HOME anyway.

Comment: You don't need the Windows installer to install Jenkins as a service. You can also simply run the WAR and then select it from the menu. And in that case your right, it isn't necessary, since Jenkins creates a jenkins.xml file, which sets the current directory as JENKINS_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the JENKINS_HOME variable following this http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2014/02/25/jenkins-home-win/

Setting JUST %JENKINS_HOME% as windows system wide environment variable didn't have any effect!

Answer (score 0):

We installed by dropping the .war into Tomcat, and could set home by **just** setting the environment variable `JENKINS_HOME` (with a service restart).