# ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.execption.AllurePluginException: Can not generate Allure Report, exit code: 255

Tags: jenkins, command-line, jenkins-plugins, allure

[protracsol] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\latest\bin\allure.bat" generate "D:\jenkins-workspace\workspace\protracsol\allure-results" -o "D:\jenkins-workspace\workspace\protracorsol\allure-report"
\Jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\latest\bin.. was unexpected at this time.
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.execption.AllurePluginException: Can not generate Allure Report, exit code: 255

Comment: Could you please specify more details about the problem? Allure Plugin version, allure command line version, Jenkins version? Some steps to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @DmitryBaev Thanks for your input, please go through the following Github url as I have mentioned the same issue in detail: [https://github.com/jenkinsci/allure-plugin/issues/86]

Comment: Removed ']' from the end of url: https://github.com/jenkinsci/allure-plugin/issues/86

Answer (score 1):

I have downgraded my allure commandline to version 2.13.9 under Jenkins' Global Tool Configuration.

[image: Jenkins - Global Tool Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared because of Jenkins, when I used its windows installer version so I faced this issue. Once I uninstall the jenkins windows installer and then installed again **jenkins.war** this issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

update the commandline tool in jenkins to the latest version. I encountered the same issue and doing this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and my problem was that the path was too long for the allure report. I changed JAVA_HOME and it works for me. instructions here [How to change Jenkins default folder on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689139/how-to-change-jenkins-default-folder-on-windows%C2%A0)

Answer (score 0):

allure-cli : allure-2.13.9 - worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).