# how to setup jenkins on win10 to use cygwin bash

Tags: bash, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cygwin, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to run the `sh` step in jenkins with Cygwin? What I have tried does not work.

To get `sh` step working with cygwin I used the config screen `http://<jenkins>:8080/configure` and I set the Shell Executable to run `C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe` But when running a test pipeline

```
node {
    stage('1'){
        bat "dir C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe"
        sh 'ls ..'
    }
}
```

this is the result.

```
Running on Jenkins in J:\workspace\try_shellx
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (1)
[Pipeline] bat

J:\workspace\try_shellx>dir C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe 
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9CDC-D180

 Directory of C:\cygwin64\bin

01/27/2017  01:13 PM           739,859 bash.exe
               1 File(s)        739,859 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  294,634,586,112 bytes free
[Pipeline] sh
sh: C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
```

So the `sh "ls .."` is not able to execute because bash cant be found but `dir C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe` is found with a `bat` step

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out finally. Its confusing because of forward and backslashes and would not work without the bat file for unknown reason. 1st step is to make a copy of the `Cygwin.bat` usually in `c:\cygwin64\` dir

```
copy C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat C:\cygwin64\CygwinForJenkins.bat
```

edit `C:\cygwin64\CygwinForJenkins.bat` to look like this.

```
@echo off

c:\cygwin64\bin\bash %*
```

then set `Shell executable` setting in "Configure System" management screen to point to that new bat file and ignore all errors that may show you. **Note the non DOS forward slashes.**

[image]

Now when you execute an `sh "find ."` or other linux command, the command is wrapped by jenkins in a temp script, and called this way.

```
C:/cygwin64/CygwinForJenkins.bat -xe J:/workspace/try_shellx@tmp/durable-aa951084/script.sh
```

`CygwinForJenkins.bat` then passes the temp script to the cygwin bash.exe like this using the DOS arg glob `%*`

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\bash -xe J:/workspace/try_shellx@tmp/durable-aa951084/script.sh
```

Additionally you will need the `C:\cygwin64\bin` in your windows SYSTEM path (found under the control panel under System or use the search seen below). This is because Jenkins also adds nohup commands which is only available in that path.

[image]
[image]

If you are having problems with this setup you can use `set` to show your windows env in the bat file. And setting `@echo on` will show all commands in the DOS environment which is how I arrived at the solution.

I have my jenkins under `J:\\workspace` and I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689139/how-to-change-jenkins-default-folder-on-windows/29710633) solution to do that

Windows subsystem for Linux (WSL) would not work with this because it does not understand the forward slash notation in paths that Jenkins passes cygwin bash. The durable task plugin does this `scriptPath.replace("\\", "/")` [seen about here in the source](https://github.com/jenkinsci/durable-task-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/durabletask/BourneShellScript.java#L279). So you have to undo this replace in the bat script before you pass it to WSL and would look something like this.

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -xe J:\\workspace\\try_shellx@tmp\\durable-aa951084\\script.sh
```

You could probably do that with sed like command for Windows. I just didn't bother going that far.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible way to do it. One tip I have for you is never mess around with backslash paths on Windows, except as a last resort. Backslash screws up everything. But what most people don't know is the Windows kernel understands forwards slash. Try this in cmd.exe:      dir "C:/Users"      works huh? Also there is a cygwin command called cygpath that converts path formats... but since I never user backslash I've never had to mess with it in decades of Windows and cygwin use. Try setting your shell to C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe